# Overload the shift operators of std::bitset

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, std-bitset

I'd like to use the shift operators as doing a bit rotation **instead** of their actual bit shift. This is my expected behavior:

```
std::bitset<8> b8("1010"); // b8 = 00001010 
b8 <<= 5;                  // b8 = 01000001
```

So I try and overloaded the `<<=` operator, referencing the `bitset` definition, as followed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

template <size_t size>
bitset<size>& bitset<size>::operator<< (size_t pos) noexcept { // an error at here

}
```

I've got an error at keyword `operator`:

> Out-of-line definition of 'operator<<' does not match any declaration in 'bitset<_Size>'

How can I fix it? My env. is:

- Xcode : Version 9.1 (9B55)
- LLVM(`llvm-g++ -v`) : Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)

Comment: You didn't show us what you actually did. How are we to tell you the appropriate fix?

Comment: @StoryTeller I mean the error occured at the definition line, remain part is typical .. btw edited question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::bitset::operator<<=` is a member function of the template class `std::bitset`. You cannot redefine this operator. And you cannot even hide it with another:

```
template <std::size_t size>
std::bitset<size>& operator<<=(std::bitset<size>& bitset, std::size_t count) noexcept {
    // ...
    return bitset;
}
```

This compiles but achieves nothing since when you write `b8 <<= 5`, unqualified-id lookup finds `std::bitset::operator<<=` before considering your free function.

You should use another operator, define a `rotate` function, or define a wrapper rotate class:

```
struct rotate
{
    rotate(std::size_t n) : value(n) {}
    std::size_t value;
};


template <std::size_t size>
std::bitset<size>& operator<<=(std::bitset<size>& bitset, rotate r) noexcept {
    bitset = bitset << r.value | bitset >> (size-r.value);
    return bitset;
}
```

usage:

```
std::bitset<8> b8("1010"); // b8 = 00001010 
b8 <<= rotate(5);          // b8 = 01000001
```

[demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5781fe9bceda3cba)

Comment: Thanks! My lack of cpp concepts... you mean an operator(member function) std template class cannot be overloaded(=redefined)?

Comment: @홍한석 You cannot change the meaning of an existing member operator. And I think it's better that way, as to not surprise the reader.

Comment: OK. Accepts your revision. Thanks for your kindness again.