# Avoiding ambiguity in overload resolution

Tags: parameters, c++17, ambiguous

This is a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55998550/1757805) question so if you need to see the Register class please refer to that question. Now based on the supplied answer I have written a function to do just that. I have 2 versions of the function one that will store the results back into the original and one that will return a copy. Here are my functions:

```
template<std::uint64_t N>
void reverseBitOrder( Register<N>& reg ) {
    auto str = reg.register_.to_string();
    std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
    auto x = vpc::Byte(str);
    reg.register_ = x;
}

// Extra unused parameter to avoid ambiguity
template<std::uint64_t N>
Register<N> reverseBitOrder(Register<N>& reg, bool _x_ /*not used*/ ) {
    auto str = reg.register_.to_string();
    std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
    auto x = vpc::Byte(str);
    Register<N> temp;
    temp.register_ = x;
    return temp;
}
```

The first one saves the value, the second returns a copy. My question is on the 2<sup>nd</sup> function I ended up adding a second parameter that is not used in order to avoid ambiguity due to overload resolution as functions can not be resolved on return types alone. So when I call this function I would have to pass either `0`, `1`, `true` or `false` to the function which has no effect.

Overall this in itself is not a very big deal, however, it doesn't seem very clean and concise to me. Are there any other ways to achieve this? I prefer not to make this a function of the class. My Register class or struct is complete as is and any kind of operations done on a register will be done by functions that take a reference to one or more register objects.

Comment: Do you really need two functions for this? Why not just use the function that returns a copy for both purposes? You can just assign the return value to the original variable if required.

Comment: @P.W True, but I was trying to keep the name of the function the same as it does the same thing the only difference; I did want two different functions for each purpose, one to overwrite the value and one to preserve and return a copy of the new value.

Comment: @P.W I guess I could have the bool parameter and default it to false and do an overwrite but if true is passed for copy then branch to another section,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) to achieve this.

The `return` type of function template `reverseBitOrder` should be `std::optional<vpc::Register<N>>`.

The function template should be modified to:

```
template<std::uint64_t N>
std::optional<vpc::Register<N>> reverseBitOrder(vpc::Register<N>& reg, bool _x_ = false) {

    auto str = reg.register_.to_string();
    std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
    vpc::Register<N> temp;    

    if(_x_) //return copy
    {
        temp.register_ = vpc::Byte(str); //since register_ is a vpc::Byte. Generalize accordingly.
        return temp;
    }
    else //save in the same variable
    {
        reg.register_ = vpc::Byte(str);        
        return {};
    }
}
```

[**`Live Demo here`**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sDhgdSlyUditNwy1).

But you don't really need to use `std::optional`, since there is really no "failure" case in the function template.

Comment: I tried your implementation above but I was forced to have to use `auto` when returning a copied value. I'd rather store it into an instance of another Register. So I opted to do what you did here but without `std::optional`. My return type is just a `Register<N>`. Works like a charm! I had thought about branching the code in a single function... but was also leaning toward separate functions...

Comment: This works good for `Register<8>` which is default size, but when I try to use it for larger registers, it is failing because of `reg.register_ = Byte(str)` ...

Comment: @FrancisCugler: Please see the comment after the assignment statement in the `if` clause. You have defined `register_ ` as `vpc::Byte` in the `Register` structure. You will have to generalize it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, both functions compute `x` and store it in a `Register<N>`, but one returns said object by value while the other stores the result in the function's argument `reg`.

**Technically**, this can be done by overloading on constness by defining those two functions:

```
template<std::uint64_t N> void reverseBitOrder( Register<N>& reg );
template<std::uint64_t N> Register<N> reverseBitOrder( Register<N> const& reg );
```

While this technically answers your question, that would be terrible design.
If I'm not mistaken, the real issue is that what you want is this:

```
// Behaviour 1: value stored in reg
reverseBitOrder(reg);

// Behaviour 2: value stored in val, reg left untouched
auto val = reverseBitOrder(reg);
```

The problem with this is that whether the returned value is used or not is not something you can detect from inside the function.

---

**The proper way** to have one function do two things here would be to have a function with this signature:

```
template<std::uint64_t N> void reverseBitOrder( Register<N> const& inputReg, Register<N>& outputReg );
```

That function would use `inputReg` to compute `x` then store the result in `outputReg`, meaning you would use it like this:

```
// Behaviour 1: value stored in reg
reverseBitOrder(reg, reg);

// Behaviour 2: value stored in val, reg leftuntouched
reverseBitOrder(reg, val);
```

---

Now, if that *really* doesn't do it for you, there is **a way to get the syntaxic sugar** you're looking for, at the cost of unneeded complexity and of adding a constructor to `Register<N>`. It would look roughly like this:

```
// Forward declaration
template<std::uint64_t N>
class Register;

// Proxy class
template<std::uint64_t N>
struct RegisterProxy
{
    Register<N>* reg;
    TypeOfX x;

    ~RegisterProxy()
    {
        if (reg)
        {
            reg->register = x;
        }
    }
};

// Modified Register class
template<std::uint64_t N>
class Register
{
    ...

    Register(RegisterProxy& proxy)
    {
        ...
        register = proxy.x;
        proxy.reg = nullptr;
        ...
    }

    ...

    // Define the matching assignment operator too

    ...
};

// Your function
template<std::uint64_t N>
RegisterProxy<N> reverseBitOrder( Register<N>& reg )
{
    auto str = reg.register_.to_string();
    std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
    auto x = vpc::Byte(str);
    return RegisterProxy{reg, x};
}
```

That allows you to do

```
// Behaviour 1: temporary object immediately destroyed and value stored in reg
reverseBitOrder(reg);

// Behaviour 2: constructor called, value stored in val
//              the temporary object's destructor doesn't do anything, reg left untouched
auto val = reverseBitOrder(reg);
```

I can't recommend doing that though, it's more trouble than it's worth. I suggest using the solution I called "the proper way". It the least complicated and the one which is the hardest to use wrong later

Comment: I appreciate the effort and there is some good advice there, however I'm trying to keep Register trivially copyable; so I need for its default constructor, copy constructor, etc. to all be default.

Comment: Yeah, as I said, using proxy and all is more trouble than it's worth. The proper way to do what you want to do is the one with inputReg and outputReg

Comment: I modified my answer a bit to make it clearer what I actually recommend doing